How can I open a Dialog when I click a specific date?
so I'm trying to build a scheduling app, and what I'm trying to do right now is when I click a specific date, It open a dialog container. I'm using ShadCN Date-picker
calendar-picker.tsx
"use client";


import { Calendar } from "@/components/ui/calendar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label"

export function CalendarPicker() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date | undefined>(new Date());

  return (
    <Calendar
      mode="single"
      selected={date}
      onSelect={setDate}
      className="shadow border rounded-md h-full w-full flex"
      classNames={{
        months:
          "flex w-full flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0 flex-1",
        month: "space-y-4 w-full flex flex-col",
        table: "w-full h-full border-collapse space-y-1",
        head_row: "",
        row: "w-full mt-2",
      }}
    />
  );
}

For example, I click April 2. A modal should appear.


They use react-day-picker inside their component.
React day picker onDayClick event 
This call back awaited:
(day: Date, activeModifiers: ActiveModifiers, e: MouseEvent) => void

You can try:
export function CalendarPicker() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<Date | undefined>(new Date());
  
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

  function onDayClick(currentDay:Date,_,_){
    // does anything with the day information...
    setVisible(true)
  }
  return (
    <>
     {/*The Dialog component implements the primereact props, use with 
     your modal*/}
    <Dialog visible={visible} onHide={() => setVisible(false)} />
    <Calendar
      mode="single"
      selected={date}
      onSelect={setDate}
      onDayClick={onDayClick}
      className="shadow border rounded-md h-full w-full flex"
      classNames={{
        months:
          "flex w-full flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0 flex-1",
        month: "space-y-4 w-full flex flex-col",
        table: "w-full h-full border-collapse space-y-1",
        head_row: "",
        row: "w-full mt-2",
      }}
    />
    </>
  );
}

You have more than events in the doc for many behavior.
The onDayClick event is listen by the library, you can also trigger it for add your custom behavior onClick on the day element.
You can too control with date if its specific date or nothing.
Have a nice day, say me if the answer help you.
